# DX11 C++ Shader can't receive Instance Buffer content

Tags: c++, shader, directx-11

i would like to draw Instances of an obj File. After i implemented the Instancing instead of drawing each Object by his own draw() function (which worked just fine), the Instances are not positioned correctly. Probably the data from the InstanceBuffer is not set in the shader correctly.

D3DMain.cpp - creating input layout

```
struct INSTANCE {
//D3DXMATRIX matTrans;
    D3DXVECTOR3 
};

/***/

// create the input layout object
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
{
    //vertex buffer
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0,  12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0,  24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},

    //instance buffer
    {"INSTTRANS", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 1, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1},
    //{"INSTTRANS", 1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1},
    //{"INSTTRANS", 2, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1},
    //{"INSTTRANS", 3, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1},
};
if (FAILED(d3ddev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 4, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout))) throw(std::string("Input Layout Creation Error"));
d3ddevcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
```

World.cpp - setting up instance buffer

```
    std::vector<INSTANCE> instanceBuffer;
    INSTANCE insertInstance;

    D3DXMATRIX scaleMat, transMat;
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&scaleMat, 50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);

    int i=0;
    for (std::list<SINSTANCES>::iterator it = sInstances.begin(); it != sInstances.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it).TypeID == typeId) {
            //do something
            D3DXMatrixTranslation(&transMat, (*it).pos.x, (*it).pos.y, (*it).pos.z);
            insertInstance.matTrans = (*it).pos;//scaleMat * transMat;
            instanceBuffer.push_back(insertInstance);
            i++;
        }
    }
    instanceCount[typeId] = i;


    //create new IB
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC instanceBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&instanceBufferDesc, sizeof(instanceBufferDesc));
    instanceBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    instanceBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(INSTANCE) * i;
    instanceBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    instanceBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    instanceBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA instanceData;
    ZeroMemory(&instanceData, sizeof(instanceData));
    instanceData.pSysMem = &instanceBuffer[0];

    if (FAILED(d3ddev->CreateBuffer(&instanceBufferDesc, &instanceData, &instanceBufferMap[typeId]))) throw(std::string("Failed to Update Instance Buffer"));
```

OpenDrawObj.cpp - drawing .obj file

```
UINT stride[2] = {sizeof(VERTEX), sizeof(INSTANCE)};
    UINT offset[2] = {0, 0};

    ID3D11Buffer* combinedBuffer[2] = {meshVertBuff, instanceBuffer};
    d3ddevcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    d3ddevcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 2, combinedBuffer, stride, offset);
    d3ddevcon->IASetIndexBuffer(meshIndexBuff, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    std::map<std::wstring, OBJMATERIAL>::iterator fit;
    for (std::vector<DRAWLIST>::iterator it = drawList.begin(); it != drawList.end(); it++) {
        fit = objMaterials.find((*it).material);
        if (fit != objMaterials.end()) {
            if ((*fit).second.texture != NULL) {
                d3ddevcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &((*fit).second.texture));
            }
            d3ddevcon->DrawIndexedInstanced((*it).indexCount, instanceCount, (*it).startIndex, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

the drawing function (above) is called here: I pass the instance buffer (map(int, ID3D11Buffer*) and the instance numbers)

```
(*it).second->draw(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0, instanceBufferMap[typeId], instanceCount[typeId]);
```

shader.hlsl

```
struct VIn
{
float4 position : POSITION;
float3 normal : NORMAL;
float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
//row_major float4x4 instTrans : INSTTRANS;
float4 instTrans : INSTTRANS;
uint instanceID : SV_InstanceID;
};



VOut VShader(VIn input)
{
VOut output;

//first: transforming instance
//output.position = mul(input.instTrans, input.position);
output.position = input.position;
output.position.xyz *= 50.0; //scale
output.position.z += input.instTrans.z; //apply only z value

float4 transPos = mul(world, output.position); //transform position with world matrix

output.position = mul(view, transPos);  //project to screen
```

the "input.instTrans" in the last file is incorrect and contains ramdom data.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Nothing stands out as obviously wrong. One thought I had is that perhaps 'D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT' doesn't work across multiple vertex streams and perhaps it's not set the offset of the INSTTRANS elements to 0, 16, 32, 48 as you might expect.
Another thing to try would be to pass through a single float4 (not a matrix) and just try and get translation working before moving on to an entire matrix with scale in.

Comment: I tried to pass through just the translation vector and only apply the x component to the vertex positions. I changed the 'D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT' to manually offsets, too. This is what it looks like after the adjustments: http://i43.tinypic.com/w0knrr.png the funny thing is that the length of this 'bar' changes when the camera moves.

Is it possible that passing the instance buffer through several functions as a parameter do any damage?

Comment: Have you trief using PIX For Windows, the Graphics Debugger built into the Pro+ versions of VS2012/2013, AMD GPU PerfStudio, Nvidia nSight or Intel GPA? They should all be capable of showing you the vertex buffer and tell you where you've gone wrong. 
Alternately if you can provide an executable or a compileable/runnable project then we might stand a better chance of getting to the bottom of it.

Comment: Wow, these tools are actually really cool ;) Okay here i have saved the vertex buffer: http://textuploader.com/1knv (the format is the same as VIn (above)) Apparently the transformation coordinates are put through, but they are not put per instance. Thank you for the great help by now, but i have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Which tool gave you that vertex buffer output? If you can perform a capture using PIX For Windows (from the DXSDK) you could then upload the saved frame/capture file and I might be able to take a look. A binary version would still be more useful though...

Comment: I took this output from AMD GPU PerfStudio, but i realized its only the content of the vertex buffer, not the data put through the shader. PIX didn't work for me, so i uploaded the binary http://www.file-upload.net/download-8538678/Release.zip.html

Comment: It looks like you haven't been running with the debug graphics layer turned on as PIX is showing a lot of warnings and also errors when it analyses your application. Pass in 'D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG' when creating your device and you should be able to see these warnings and errors. These are all the warnings and errors I see in PIX, but you'll have to run the game yourself with the debug layer turned on to see which event they correspond to: http://pastebin.com/cfdjk2Df

Comment: Time EID Type Context Message
3 3931 Message Render D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexedInstanced: Input Assembler - Vertex Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. The input stage requires Semantic/Index (INSTTRANS,0) as input, but it is not provided by the output stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #342: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_SEMANTICNAME_NOT_FOUND ]
this one may be the error i am looking for

Comment: I removed "float4 instTrans : INSTTRANS; uint instanceID : SV_InstanceID;" from my shader and i got no error, there is probably an error in the Input layout. If i rename "INSTTRANS" to "TEXCOORD0" then CreateInputLayout throws the exception. Calling d3ddevcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout); each time before drawing didn't help either.

Comment: I assume you're not still passing '7' through for the number of input elements as per your code snippet?

Comment: I've checked that, but i changed that to 4 earlier. Btw, i was able to get rid of all warnings, except of that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the bug, it was at an totally unexpected location...
So here is the code snippet:

```
ID3D10Blob *VS, *VS2, *PS, *PS2; //<- i only used VS and PS before

//volume shader
if (FAILED(D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"resources/volume.hlsl", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_PREFER_FLOW_CONTROL | D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0))) throw(std::string("Volume Shader Error 1"));
if (FAILED(D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"resources/volume.hlsl", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_PREFER_FLOW_CONTROL | D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0))) throw(std::string("Volume Shader Error 2"));
// encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
if (FAILED(d3ddev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pvolumeVS))) throw(std::string("Volume Shader Error 1A"));
if (FAILED(d3ddev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pvolumePS))) throw(std::string("Volume Shader Error 2A"));

//sky shader
if (FAILED(D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"resources/sky.hlsl", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL3, 0, 0, &VS2, 0, 0))) throw(std::string("Sky Shader Error 1"));
if (FAILED(D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"resources/sky.hlsl", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL3, 0, 0, &PS2, 0, 0))) throw(std::string("Sky Shader Error 2"));
// encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
if (FAILED(d3ddev->CreateVertexShader(VS2->GetBufferPointer(), VS2->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pskyVS))) throw(std::string("Sky Shader Error 1A"));
if (FAILED(d3ddev->CreatePixelShader(PS2->GetBufferPointer(), PS2->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pskyPS))) throw(std::string("Sky Shader Error 2A"));
```

Using two buffers for compiling the shaders solved the problem, though i have no idea why. Thank you for the support, though ;)